# Jade dynamic form placeholder

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

Folks,
  Trying to generate a form dynamically.  upstreamData gets passed in, and contains values which I would like to be prefilled in the form.  The following error is seen:

```
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
> 22|   input.form-control(type='text', placeholder= #{val.rate.N} )
```

code that does not work:

```
form(action='/foo', method='POST', role='form')
    legend Foo Form
    .form-group.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1
        - each val, key in upstreamData
            label(for='') #{val.name.S}
            input.form-control(type='text', placeholder= #{val.rate.N} )
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

code that works:

```
form(action='/foo', method='POST', role='form')
    legend Foo Form
    .form-group.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1
        - each val, key in upstreamData
            label(for='') #{val.name.S}
            input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='bar' )
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap this in quotes, use simple variable, assign it to something else and then use that...

1. Method: Wrap it:

   input.form-control(type='text',placeholder='#{val.rate.N}')
2. Method: simple variable like in Crnag's answer:

   input.form-control(type='text',placeholder=val.rate.N)
3. method: assign it to something else then use that:

   - var myVar = val.rate.N   // Good for doing some logic when needed
     input.form-control(type='text',placeholder=myVar)

Each of them will add standard html doublequotes around the placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using #{variable} Simply use:

```
input.form-control(type='text', placeholder=val.rate.N )
```